# Why MapKit framework must be linked to every file while CoreData framework must not?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Linked frameworks and libraries in my project written in Swift:

[image]

Suppose I have two files in my project: `AppDelegate.swift` and `ViewController.swift`

My import statements in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData
import MapKit
```

So simply here I can use for example: `NSManagedObject` and `MKMapView` classes.

In `ViewController.swift` I do not have any import statements, but I can use there `NSManagedObject` opposite to `MKMapView`. Why?

Shouldn't be in Swift that one framework imported in one file should be visible to other files? Why `CoreData` is visible to all, but `MapKit` is not?

I also use `Project-Bridging-Header.h` in my project with following import statements:

```
@import AFNetworking;
@import Crashlytics;
@import Fabric;
@import FBSDKCoreKit;
@import FBSDKLoginKit;
@import MagicalRecord;
@import MTBBarcodeScanner;
@import QRCode;
@import SVProgressHUD;
```

Comment: Strange, I always have to state that I import CoreData before I can use it's classes.

Answer (score 1):

- Swift works with **modules**.
- Every file is visible to other files in **the same module** without any imports.
- Every class created in different module can be accessed outside only via `import` statement. Frameworks are different modules. If you need to access framework you need to import it for **every file** where you gonna use it.
- `Bridging-Header.h` file distributes other modules/frameworks to **every file** in module where such header exists.
- if module **A** import module **B**, and you need to access both of them in module **C**, it is enough to import just module **A** in your **C** module.